# C# - Using switches when launching processes

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have code that launches a program:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c test.exe \"\" > output.txt").WaitForExit();
```

Although instead I would like to use a parameter / switch with test.exe:

```
test.exe -F input.txt
```

How could this be done?

Comment: I think you need to look over the documentation for the `Process` and `ProcessStartInfo` classes in much more detail. Your usage suggests you haven't done so; you shouldn't need to be running `cmd.exe` and you shouldn't need to redirect the output from the command you are running. `Process` and `ProcessStartInfo` can handle all of that for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Process.Start - using parameters with it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392409/c-process-start-using-parameters-with-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ProcessStartInfo.Arguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx). There is an example in the msdn page.

```
    var process = new Process
                      {
                          StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                                          {
                                              FileName = "test.exe",
                                              Arguments = "-F input.txt",
                                          }
                      };
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: how would I do the output though? (output.txt) ?

Comment: @Michael can't you do `Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/c test.exe -f input.txt > output.txt").WaitForExit();` ?